# Batch script pass multiple parameters to call

Tags: windows, function, batch-file, parameters, procedure

I have written a script that contains a function that should loop through a list and return a value given the index of the item in said list. I have a function called: `:find` that should take 2 arguments: the list and the item position. I am unsure of how to process the multiple parameters in the function. This script runs fine if I replace `%LIST%` with `%MY_LIST%` inside the loop and I remove the `%MY_LIST%` from the argument list tht is passed to `call :find`, but I really want to know how to pass multiple arguments. I take it that they are just passed to the function as a whole string...

```batch
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
cls

:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: Variable declarations
:: ----------------------------------------------------------
set RETURN=-1
set MY_LIST=("foo" "bar" "baz")
set TARGET_INDEX=1

:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: Main procedure
:: ----------------------------------------------------------
call :log "Finding item %TARGET_INDEX%..."
call :find %MY_LIST% %TARGET_INDEX%
call :log "The value is: %RETURN%"
goto Exit

:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: Function declarations
:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:find
call :log "Called `:find` with params: [%*]"
set /a i=0
set LIST=%~1 & shift

for %%a in %LIST% do (
    if !i! == %~1 (
        set RETURN=%%a
    )
    set /a i=!i!+1
)
goto:EOF

:printDate
for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('echo %DATE%') do (
  set mydate=%%c/%%a/%%b)
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/:./ " %%a in ('echo %TIME%') do (
  set mytime=%%a:%%b:%%c)
echo|set /p="[%mydate% %mytime%] "
goto:EOF

:log
call :printDate
echo %~1
goto:EOF

:: ----------------------------------------------------------
:: End of script
:: ----------------------------------------------------------

:Exit
```

---

**Update**

My script now works fine; thanks to nephi12. http://pastebin.com/xGdFWmnM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
call :find "%MY_LIST%" %TARGET_INDEX%
goto :EOF

:find
echo %~1 %~2
goto :EOF
```

they are passed the same as args to the script... `;)`

Comment: That worked. Thanks, but do you know why it works? Also, here is my working script! http://pastebin.com/xGdFWmnM

Comment: the "'s pass it as one parameter, quotes and all. the ~ in %~1 removes quotes if they are there.

Comment: The script looks great! It is well put together, and efficient.

Comment: This solution is limited to 9 values in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another method to do an index lookup on a space delimited list of values. Define the list without enclosing parentheses. Single words don't need to be quoted. Phrases with space, tab, semicolon, or equal must be quoted. Also values with special characters like `&` and `|` should be quoted.

Then reverse the order of your :FIND arguments - first the index, followed by the actual list. Use SHIFT in a FOR /L loop to get the desired index value into the first argument.

One advantage of this solution is that it can support any number of values, as long as they fit within the 8191 character per line limit. The nephi12 solution is limited to 9 values.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set MY_LIST=foo bar baz "Hello world!"
call :find %~1 %MY_LIST%
echo return=%return%
exit /b

:find  index  list...
for /L %%N in (1 1 %~1) do shift /1
set "return=%~1"
exit /b
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I think it answers your question.  Put it in a bat file and then build whatever else you need around it after you see this work.  Execute it with a quoted string from a command prompt.  YourBatFile "Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 Etc"

```
@echo off
call :DoSomethingWithEach %~1
goto :eof

:DoSomethingWithEach
for %%a in (%*) do echo.%%a
goto :eof
```